# UIView addSubview nor working in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, addsubview

barView I have a Table View and, in each cell, I want to draw some statistic bars. I have an empty `UIView` created in my custom cell, its name is `mainView` and it is the view where the chart is drawn.

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I'm doing this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGRect barRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 10);

    UIView *barView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:barRect];
    [barView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [cell.mainView addSubview:barView];

    return cell;
}
```

The `barView` is not displaying on loading. It only shows after I change and return from another tab or **after the cell goes out of the screen**.

**Notes:**

- I have tried `[cell.mainView setNeedsDisplay];`
- I have a header made with another custom cell.

Comment: how you have add mainView in UITableViewCell?

Comment: I created a custom class named CustomCell and added a property IBOutlet called mainView. Then I assigned the class to the cell and the IBOutlet to the view in interfaceBuilder.

Comment: What is `initView`? Did you mean `barView` instead? Otherwise it's pretty clear that you don't see anything, since you created just an empty view.

Comment: use just [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier]; and tell me is there any change.

Comment: Sorry, there is no `initView`, all `barView`, it was a copy-paste error when posting it here. I've corrected it in the question. The code in the program is OK. Still no working...

Comment: No changes at all... Thank you @CRDave

Comment: It's curious how the barView appears after the cell goes out of the screen. It's like the view is drawn before the changes are produced and then, when it goes aut and comes back, it's drawn properly...

Comment: is this problem only with mainView? I mean if you use [cell. contentView addSubview:barView]; than is it working?

Comment: Never think about it but no, not working neither...

Comment: I fixed it forcing the table to redraw with `[self.tableView reloadData];` in `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`.

Comment: What do you mean by redraw? I think it needs to be called at least once, for it to work. Either it is in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear. The fact that it works right after you call it in viewDidAppear simply means that in any calls before it, your datasource wasn't ready. This got resolved by the time you hit viewDidAppear, and it works.

Comment: I was calling `[self.tableView reloadData];` in `viewWillAppear`. All the data in the cell was OK but the barView. All the table was updated but the charts. It seems that this kind of changes don't get updated when reloading the data in the WILL Appear function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved it easily with:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

It seems that adding a subview cant be done before the view is created in the window, before the cells are completely loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        CGRect barRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 10);
        UIView *barView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:barRect];
        [barView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [cell addSubview:barView]; // use cell.mainView if you have that created somewhere other than here (like IB)
    }

    return cell;
}
```

`dequeueResuable...` can return a nil cell. So you need to have a check, to see if you should alloc/init a new cell. In the code I gave you if `dequeueResuable...` returns you a proper cell then it would have been created with the subview intact already. So no need to re-add it (hence creating it only in `if (!cell)`)

Comment: Thank you but this do not solve my problem. (I have tried your code) My cell is always created properly, all the labels and the contents are loaded correctly and their values are OK. I use `cell.customLabel.text =...` and everything is OK. The `cell.mainView` is also OK. It's a view I created in interface builder and I can change its color with `[cell.mainView setBackgroundColor:...]` Everything seems to work but drawing a new view inside this `mainView`. And the way I solved it was reloading `tableView` data in `viewDidAppear`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your description clearly indicates you are filling your barView outside this function. So that it becomes visible only after transition.
Or you are simply overwriting it (or even overwriting mainview) outside what you have provided here.

Check your viewdidload and viewdidappear and the likes.

Comment: Thank you but there is not `barView`or `mainView` outside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function